# How to remove index.php from url in Zend Framework

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

I am developing this app using Zend Framework 1.12. I wan to get rid off the `index.php` using .htaccess. Right now my url looks like this:

```
http://foo.com:10080/Reports_Century/public/index.php/reports/neworders
```

I want to be able to look like this

```
http://foo.com:10080/Reports_Century/public/reports/neworders
```

Is it possible?
my htaccess looks has the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}-s [OR]
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}-l [OR]
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}-d
RewriteRule ^ .* $ - [NC, L]
RewriteRule ^ .* $ index.php [NC, L]
```

thank you.

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess file?

Comment: it id inside the public folder

Comment: Thanks for your response, posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your `public/.htacess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Reports_Century/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: didn't work. I am still getting 404. Shouldn't i been getting a 500 error code instead of 404. How do i know for sure mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Which URL did you use to test this rule?

Comment: Should it not be: `http://foo.com:10080/Reports_Century/public/reports/neworders` You are missing `/public/` in your URL

Comment: even with the public it does not work.How can i check for sure if my rewrite is enabled?

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled otherwise you will get 500 error. Do you have any other rule in your .htaccess OR is there any other .htaccess in the system?

Comment: no that's the only htaccess file in the project. There are other htaccess files in other projects(different folders, etc). the rules that i have are the ones you posted. Do i need to do anything in hhtpd.conf?

Comment: ok i changed this line in httpd.conf:
AllowOverride All(it was "none" before). Now i am getting the following error message:No input file specified.

Comment: What is your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` set to?

Comment: And `/Reports_Century/public/` is directory with full path `C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/Reports_Century/public/`?

Comment: yes. the full path is:C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\Reports_Century\public\

Comment: i just tried and didn't work. Should i leave the AllowOverride to None or All for my document root folder?
If i leave as "None" i get the error "no input file specified".But if i leave as "All" i get a 404. Which one shoulsd i leave as?

Comment: It should be `AllowOverride All` and that required Apache restart

Comment: just changed to All and keep getting the error: "No input file specified."

Comment: Most likely you have local config issues in your setup

Comment: you mean in the application.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this right below `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ /public/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: it didn't work Jon. Any thoughts? I am getting a 404

Answer (score 0):

Version without index.php is default in Zend. You don't have to change default .htaccess.
I bet you didn't enabled rewrite module in apache* or disabled rewriting in config.

* copy `rewrite.load` file to `mods-enabled` folder in apache (on ubuntu it's in `/etc/apache`)

Answer (score 0):

finally found where the issue was. The problem was the $1 after index.php/.

the final .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Reports_Century/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [L]
```

@Anubhava giving you a plus  one for speding the time and helping me with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to activate "AllowOverride All" for your directory in `apache2/sites-enabled/default`:

```
    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```