# Removing index.php from url in zend framework 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am having problem removing this index.php using all above solution. can any one help.
My system configuration is ubuntu 14.04 and i am using zend framework 1.12.

my `.htaccess` file has

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /Reports_Century/public/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [L]
```

Any other setting for removing `index.php` from URL?

Comment: Not really following what you mean by removing index.php?

Comment: @Adip Patel see this .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381543/how-to-remove-index-php-from-url-in-zend-framework

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(\.wav)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css|otf|ttf)$ index.php
```